# Meta tags and language

Tags: html, meta-tags

I have a website writteng in greek.

`<meta name="keywords" content="" />` can I use greek language in content or just in english?

If I can write them using greek chars, do I have to add anything to meta tag?

Thank you

Comment: it's also a good idea to add this `<meta name="language" content="greek"> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any character you want from the character set you are using. Just make sure that your web server send the correct character set headers in the HTTP request. You may also add a `<meta>` element specifying the charset, but it's not strictly necessary.

I use UTF-8 in these examples as I think it's a code charset and prefer to use it myself. It's on its way to take over as the standard charset on the web.

HTTP header which should be sent by the web server:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Optional `<meta>` element for your document:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Thank you. I use utf-8 as well. One more thing. If I type greek in google using english characters e.g "sigkrino" (equals compare) google brings up results as if I had typed compare. That means "sigkrino" is specified in <meta> or is something else?

Comment: @Pavlos1316, interpreting the meaning and translation is Google's thing, has little to do with `<meta>`

Comment: Google doesn't care about your meta keyword tags. They look at the actual content on your site to see if it is relevant to the search query. Sometimes they use words from other languages, sometimes they don't.

Comment: So in order to bring my site up to google search engine I have to use as more text as possible???

Comment: Search Engine Optimization (SEO) is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but I strongly recommend you to read this: http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf It's available in other languages as well: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.se/2009/06/seo-starter-guide-now-available-in-40.html